# How do I tell if a Vim swap file is unmodified and unopen?

Tags: vim

I frequently have dozens of files open in Vim when my machine crashes, and open them all at once through a session file.  However, all the prompts about existing session files bug me.  I always choose the [d]elete option unless either:

1. The file had been modified, or
2. The file is open in another process.

I would like to automate the process through the `SwapEvent` autocmd, so that I only see those two cases; however, the only information easily accessible is `<afile>` and `v:swapname`.  The prompt shows whether the swapfile has modifications, and whether a process with its number is currently running, so I know that information is available, but how do I access it?  Will I need to fire an external process to read the swapfile?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [recover.vim - Show differences for recovered files](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3068) plugin. It has an option to diff the swap file with the saved file and offers to delete the swap file when there are no changes.

Comment: I had seen it, but its primary functionality isn't quite what I want.  Looking deeper into the source, though, it seems to call another copy of Vim and parse the output to determine the information I need.  Is there really no better way?

Comment: Christian Brabandt has published many great plugins and knows Vim's internals probably like Bram himself. If he hasn't found a different way, I'm pretty sure there isn't; don't be afraid to contact him, though.